# Why is this uncommenting macro invalid in clang but valid in msvc

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Why is this uncommenting macro invalid in clang but valid in msvc:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fd2a3ccd933618f
http://rextester.com/GFNL42397

```
#define COMMENT / ## /

int main() 
{

    COMMENT int a = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The answer box is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MSVC re-evaluates the preprocessor output while clang does not:

- clang considers the resulting // as invalid token and is correct about it. (phase 3 mentioned by @Some programmer dude is not effective here, since the preprocessor was not run yet, it will be run in phase 4, so there is no comment line to be replaced by a single space)
- MSVC re-scans the preprocessed input, and replaces the comment line with a single space. Thus, MSVC will not complain.

  See also [Preprocessor – The Token Pasting (##) Operator](http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/programming/c/preprocessor-the-token-pasting-operator)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at e.g. [this translation phase reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) you will see that comments are replaced by a single space last in phase 3, which is the phase *before* the preprocessor is run. So the code you show is not valid. Clang is correct.

Comment: In other words, comments are handled before preprocessing, so `//` created by the preprocessor is not interpreted as comment.

Comment: is it possible to only replace this macro implementation by one which produces the same effect namely commenting the line

Comment: @Gabriel There is no standard way to "comment" a line except actual comments. And in a standard-compliant compiler those should be handled before macro expansion. So no there is no portable and reliable way to "comment" a line using the preprocessor.